# Unable to access new volume when I mount the drive

Tags: mount, hard-drive, 17.04

While transferring the files to external hard disk then suddenly two of its drives went blank like below image..

[image]

Drive : i and j

and after we choose to mount then suddenly an error pops up like below image.

[image]

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Your 2nd image tells you what to do. Since NTFS is a Microsoft Secret file system, only windows and fix the problem.

Comment: May I know how that could be done, if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errors often give valuable information and here is no exception.  It helps to break it down in chunks:

```
Error mounting system-managed device /dev/sdb3/
```

Your drive located at `/dev/sdb3/` cannot be mounted due to an error.

```
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault...
```

There is a problem with NTFS (the file system on the drive).  It may have fixable errors, or it may not (if the problem is the hardware itself)

```
In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
```

This says that you should boot into Windows and inside an adminstrators command prompt **run `chkdsk C: /f`** where `C:` is the drive letter assigned by Windows.  The error advises you to reboot into Windows 2x.

Another alternative to check faulty NTFS volumes in Ubuntu is **run `ntfsfix`**.  You would do this by opening a terminal in Ubuntu and running `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb3/`  (`/dev/sdb3/` is used because this is the location of your disk on Ubuntu.)

```
If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID...
```

If this applies to your device (unlikely) then follow the instructions given to correct this error with these types of RAID configs.

---

In the case of hardware error, like a failing hard drive, there is not much that can be done except to replace the drive.  If your hard drive is failing you should make backups ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

Windows fastboot is preventing you from mounting the partition because windows is in hybrid hibernate/suspend. run "mount -o ro /dev/sdb3 /path/to/mount/to" will mount an unclean ntfs file system on /path/to/mount/to if you just want to read files off the partition. if you want to read /write that partition you must boot into windows then hold shift when selecting shut down to shut down your computer and disable fast boot temporarily them boot into Linux and try mounting the partition.